# Shape comparison language (SCL) - get shapes which intersect extent border

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query, query-task, spatial-relationship

I am trying to write a SCL string for my ArcGIS query, which should return **only** shapes which are **intersected** by a border of a rectangular shape (extent). So far the closest I've got is the following:

```
"RELATE(G2,G1,'G1 INTERSECT G2.BOUNDARY')"
```

However this also returns shapes which are fully contained within the rectangular shape and don't intersect the border. Maybe someone with SCL experience could provide a few tips?

Comment: Any reason why you can't convert the rectangle to lines and intersect these?